# work/cache table issues, heavy inserts with heavy reads

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, index, index-tuning, insert, fill-factor

we have a work table that stores availability of products. This table is updated with millions of inserts every night and medium amounts of inserts throughout the day.

during the updates, we delete all the previous info ,for that product. So over the course of a day we delete and insert 50% of the data, resulting in new rows that account for 50% of the table

The table is also read from heavily to get this information all throughout the day.

Right now we are seeing issues during heavy inserts. We have tracked this down to index splits. here are some questions:

1) The primary key is an auto number and a bunch of other columns. The auto number is first in order. Does this mean all entries will always be added to the end of index resulting in new leafs and not splits, therefore we do not need to worry about setting a lower fill factor? It's currently at 80%

2) The indexes are in random order, so should we use a lower fill factor such as 50%, it's currently at 80%.

3) is there a better pattern/process we can follow. Such as doing the inserts into another table then bulk copying the results in? The insert processes take hours. This way we alleviate some of the issues. Then the concern becomes the inserting of a lot of rows all at once.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you use primary key as the clustered index? In a mixed environment with big OLTP workload i would try to split it into 2 tables and use ETL during off hours to update the data. Otherwise you have to find a neat compromise between keeping necessary indexes and growing page splits.

Comment: yes, we have a primary key as the clustered index. it's an OLTP workload.

Comment: What kind of issues do you see particularly? Is this _non-clustered_ index split causing locking and/or slow queries? If you do not reuse key values during inserts you don't need to adjust fill factor for the clustered index. Increasing fill factor will lead to less data density and more page reads required.

Comment: Couple of questions - when you say `during the updates, we delete all the previous info` - are you wiping out all the data or just a subset ? What isolation level you are using ? How are you doing inserts - BULK LOAD, SSIS, SELECT .. INTO ?

Comment: we delete all previous info PER product. So some records stay. The data is created by inserts from a .NET program which is making multiple remote calls to get the data.

Comment: Do you use the IDENTITY field for any operations? Most likely would be JOINs since not used in INSERT, unlikely for DELETE, and it doesn't sound like you do UPDATE. Regarding "inserts from .Net based on multiple calls": is the app inserting just one record at a time? If yes, based on the multiple calls to get the data, could you gather data to create more than 1 row at a time? I can answer after getting answers to these, but for now, for #1: a) Yes, all rows are added to the end, and b) fillfactor only helps with updates to rows in the middle (sometimes) so no `UPDATE`s = FillFactor of 100.

Comment: We do not use the identity column. So that answers #1. My concern is the other indexes and inserts. The table is LOTS of deletes and inserts, never an update.

Comment: Well, #1 is only temporarily answered ;-). I still need to know about your ability to insert more than 1 record at a time, and if you delete the per-product info in a single shot or in sets of rows. And how many rows per product, on average? How many total rows in the table? And any chance of you posting the Schema in the question?

Comment: It's 1 row at a time(we will fix this by creating a load table, then copying all rows at once). The table has 1 million row, with 80% of them being refreshed every day. and probably 20% of those being refreshed 3 times a day.

Comment: I'd rather not post the schema, but lets say it's a wide table. The pk is an auto number with a guid, and 4 more varchar(20)